# Choosing seven cards from a deck

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Out of 52 cards we choose (without replacement) 7. What is the probability that we did not have any spades or we did not have any aces?
my guess is to do this as follow:
$$\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{{39 \choose 7}+{48 \choose 7}-{36 \choose 7}}{{52 \choose 7}} $$ however in the answers i have the solution is: $$\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{{36 \choose 7}}{{52 \choose 7}}$$

Which of the answers is correct? And why?

Comment: It is a mather of understanding the question.  their answer suggest there is no spades or aces (both at the same time) in the 7 cards.  Your answer is either no spades or no aces, but not necessarely both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what exactly the question is asking for.  The second answer gives the probability of drawing a hand of 7 with no aces or spades, as explained in the first comment.  However, if you interpret the question as finding the number of hands that either have no aces, or have no spades (or both), then the first answer is correct by inclusion-exclusion (there are 48 cards that are not aces and 39 that are not spades).  In short, the disparity comes out of ambiguous phrasing of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the typo (original question mentioned $57 \choose 7$), the second answer is correct.

There are only 36 cards valid (3 suits * 12 cards).

Any 7 card combination out of 36 divided by any combination out of 52 is the fraction = probability of accepted drawings.

Comment: My idea was to find a probability in a following manner: $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(spade ^\prime)+\mathbb{P}(aces ^\prime)-\mathbb{P}(spade^\prime \cap aces ^\prime)$ why this thinking is incorrect?